# CSS shorthand for positioning

Tags: css, css-position

There are any shorthand for `top` `right` `bottom` `left` or for `width` and `height` ?

I have a lot of css like this

```
#topDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:100px;
}
#centerDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:120px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#consoleDiv {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:120px;
}
```

I would like to do anything like this

```
position: absolute 10px 50px 50px 100px;
```

or

```
size: 400px 200px;
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have that. However, you can use a CSS framework (such as LESS) to create such behavior (using Parametric Mixins).

Comment: Make a .class with { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; }

Comment: @jasssonpet the example values was arbitrary, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**2021 Update**: The [`inset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) is currently gaining adoption. This property uses the same multi-value syntax as the shorthand `margin` property. For browser compatibility, please see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset#browser_compatibility).

---

No short-hand exists to combine all of these values. These are all *different* properties, unlike, for instance `background`, which has colors, images, positions and repeat instructions and as such *can* be coalesced into a short-hand form.

If you really wanted this type of control, you could use something like SASS and create a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins).

Comment: Would SASS be an overkill for this ?

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore You could definitely use that; or roll your own solution using [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/).

Comment: Not true anymore, checkout [`inset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset).

Comment: @YihaoGao Inset is currently an Editor's Draft, with no support in Safari. Neat feature, but definitely should be used sparingly at this time.

Answer (score 19):

I just found this, was looking for the same, I ended up using sass for top, bottom, left, right

here is my solution

```
@mixin position($top, $right: $top, $bottom: $top, $left: $right) {
    top: $top;
    right: $right;
    bottom: $bottom;
    left: $left;
 }
```

works like most css shorthands

`@include position(5) // all 4`

`@include position(5,4) // vertical, horizontal`

`@include position(5,4,3) // top, horizontal, bottom`

`@include position(5,4,3,2) // top, right, bottom, left`

Comment: This doesn't answer his question as he explicitly asked for css.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is no as they are different properties so can not be combined. You can however consolidate your css a little bit rather than repeating certain properties, e.g:

```
#topDiv,
#centerDiv,
#consoleDiv {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#topDiv {
    top:0;
    height:100px;
}
#centerDiv {
    top:100px;
    bottom:120px;
}
#consoleDiv {
    bottom:0;
    height:120px;
}
```

Comment: doesn't directly answer the question of combining directional properties with a position property, which is something that will probably never happen in CSS

Answer (score 2):

`inset` is what you can use in 2020 as positioning shorthand, but you need to use PostCSS and this plugin https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-inset

Example:

```
.example {
  inset: 10px 20px 80px;
}

/* becomes */

.example {
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

More info and spec here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-logical-1/#propdef-inset

Comment: Actually you can't use inset anywhere outside of Firefox right now, and that spec is only a working draft, so you shouldn't be using this property even for production Firefox sites yet. This also doesn't directly answer the question of combining directional properties with a position property, which is something that will probably never happen in CSS.

Comment: A lot of things implemented by browsers are working draft and editors draft. Anyway, like people use SASS for everything, you can use PostCSS with a bunch of js lines and start using this with a plugin https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-inset

Comment: Keep checking browser compatibility. It's documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset

Answer (score 1):

you can use **inset: top right bottom left;**.

```
#topDiv {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#centerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 100px 0 120px;
}

#consoleDiv {
    position: absolute;
    inset: auto 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want shorthand for this, you're gonna need to make what's called a mixin with Sass. Don't know what it is? Look it up!

```
@mixin position($position, $args) {
  @each $o in top right bottom left {
        $i: index($args, $o);

    @if $i and $i + 1< = length($args) and type-of(nth($args, $i + 1)) == number  {
          #{$o}: nth($args, $i + 1);
    }
  }

  position: $position;
}

@mixin absolute($args) {
        @include position("absolute", $args);
}

@mixin fixed($args) {
        @include position("fixed", $args);
}

@mixin relative($args) {
        @include position("relative", $args);
}
```

Here's a link that explains it:

http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/05/offsets-sass-mixin/

Comment: doesn't directly answer the question of combining directional properties with a position property, which is something that will probably never happen in CSS

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Inset link to inset MDN page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset)

Comment: Welcome to the comunity. Please notice somebody else already posted inset as a solution. Also, when answering a question, please avoid "Link answers" like yours. An answer should be elaborated and explanatory. For example, in this case, an example of use would have improve your answer a lot.

Comment: oh, I am sorry about that, will take of this from now onwards @ÒscarRaya