# Is it possible to specify all properties ( top,bottom,left,right ) in single line using CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I want to specify all properties ( top,right,bottom,left ) in one single line of CSS like how we are specifies `margin:50px; ( margin-top:50px,margin-right:50px,margin-bottom:50px,margin-left:50px )`

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: yes, you can use all properties in single line css

Comment: @MrLister it is most definitely possible, it's called CSS shorthand. Unifx answer shows the correct way to do it. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties for a detailed explanation :)

Comment: Ah - I am assuming you thought he was asking whether he could define the CSS rules for `top: 0px; left:0px;` etc in shorthand. I thought so too at first until I read the first answer, and then reread the question ;)

Comment: I understand the same as @Mr Lister, I think the OP wants to use shorthand with top, bottom, right and left propieties

Comment: In that case is not possible and there is a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855276/css-shorthand-for-positioning

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to do it is by using the `inset` property.

For instance, both

```
top: 5px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 8px;
right: 8px;
```

and

`inset: 5px 8px 10px 8px;`

do the same thing.

You can find deeper information & examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset

Answer (score 6):

yeah the correct way is like so.
It goes Top right bottom left.

```
margin: 10px 20px 50px 30px;
```

so its

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```

Ok so I am not to sure what you are asking. Still.

So I will try my best.

Margin works like so. There is 4 sides as you stated, top right bottom left, a clock wise motion.

You can target each one like I have done above OR if they are all the same you can do this

```
margin: 20px;
```

however if the left and right are the same and so is the top and bottom you can do this

```
margin: 20px 30px;
```

eg i use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

all the time

You can also do

```
margin: 20px 30px 10px;
```

which will target the top with 20px the right with 30px the bottom with 10px and the left with 30px

If you only want the right you can do this

margin-right: 20px;

the same goes for margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left.

Comment: It might be worth adding (for interest sake / ease of remembering) that the order follows a clockwise direction starting at the top. :)

Comment: yes i got it   my question is usually we will use sometime right:0,top:0,left:0,bottom:0, four times we need to write instead of writing like this is there any way to write in single line ( ex. margin:10px )

Comment: @Frits Which is the ONLY way I remember it - where remembering = moving by hand about :}

Comment: yeah, it comes naturally now haha, it used to mess me up all the time

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inset` like this:

```
inset: 5px 3px 1px 10px;
```

The order is `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking how to specify `margin-top`, `margin-left`, `margin-bottom` and `margin-right` on one line?

Easy:

You can use for example. `margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;`. This will result in the same as:

```
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
margin-left: 100px;
```

The same applies to the `padding` property.

See more http://devdocs.io/css/margin and http://devdocs.io/css/padding

Answer (score 0):

There is many options for value assign in on line:

1. all side same value: `margin:10px;`
2. all side need different value: `margin:10px 20px 30px 40px` (top, right, bottom, left)
3. top-bottom and left-right need same value: `margin: 10px 30px;`(top-bottom, left-right).

Same as all you can use in padding as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the inset property in CSS to define the positioning of an element within its container. It allows you to specify values for the top, right, bottom, and left sides of the element.

For instance, you can set it as follows:

```
inset: 5px 3px 1px 10px;
```

In this case, the values correspond to the top, right, bottom, and left margins, respectively. So, the element will be positioned 5 pixels from the top, 3 pixels from the right, 1 pixel from the bottom, and 10 pixels from the left within its container.

Alternatively, if you want the same pixel value for all directions, you can simplify it to:

```
inset: 3px;
```